# Combine multiple queued Azure DevOps build pipeline jobs into one run

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline

I have a custom Agent Pool with multiple Agents, each with the same capabilities. This Agent Pool is used to run many YAML build pipeline jobs called them `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, etc. Each of those `A*` jobs triggers a different YAML build pipeline job called `B`. In this scheme, multiple simultaneous completions of `A*` jobs will trigger multiple simultaneous `B` jobs. However, the `B` job is setup to self-interlock, so that only one instance can run at a time. The nice thing is that when `B` job runs, it consumes all of the existing `A*` outputs (for safety reasons, `A*` and `B` are also interlocked).

Unfortunately, this means that of the multiple simultaneous `B` jobs, most will be stuck waiting for the first to finish after it processed all of the outputs of complete `A*` jobs, and only then the rest of the queued and/or running but blocked on interlock instances of `B` job can continue one at a time, with each having nothing to consume because all of the `A*` outputs have already been processed.

Is there a watch to make Azure DevOps batch together multiple instances of job `B` together? In other words, if there is already one `B` job instance running or queued, don't add another one?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a watch to make Azure DevOps batch together multiple instances of job B together? In other words, if there is already one B job instance running or queued, don't add another one?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed**. AFAIK, there is no such way/feature to combine multiple queued build pipeline to one.

Besides, personally think that your request is reasonable. You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.